# React Swiper Property 'spaceBetween' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & RefAttributes<SwiperRef> & SwiperProps'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-swiper

I'm using React, Typescript and Swiper.
versions
React: 18.2.0
typescript: 5.2.2
swiper: 10.2.0
I get an error when using any property like that:
`Type '{ children: Element[]; spaceBetween: number; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & RefAttributes<SwiperRef> & SwiperProps'. Property 'spaceBetween' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & RefAttributes<SwiperRef> & SwiperProps'.`

```
import React from 'react';
import type { FC } from 'react';
import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from 'swiper/react';
import 'swiper/css';

interface Props {
  images: string[];
}

const ImageSwiper: FC<Props> = ({ images }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <Swiper spaceBetween={50}>
        {images.map((src, idx) => {
          return (
            <SwiperSlide key={idx}>
              <img src={src} alt='' />
            </SwiperSlide>
          );
        })}
      </Swiper>
    </>
  );
};
export default ImageSwiper;
```

Found information that you need TypeScript version 5 above. But it did not help

Comment: I changed the swiper version to 9.4.1 and this problem was solved.